# Limiting code to trigger only when data matches a requirement?

Tags: c#

I have written a system that sends an email when an alert is triggered. However, I want to customize what is sent based on the person it goes to. Each person has a unique location, which is expressed as a number (i.e. 000102). I want a string of code that executes if location = x. Here is my code that pulls the location:

```
if (IN_PRODUCTION && sendAlert)
  {                                 
  //get location, assetDetail and system of dataSensor
   MainSystem dataSensorMainSystem = null;
   Subsystem dataSensorSubsystem = null;
   SystemComponent dataSensorSystemComponent = null;
    Location location = null;

     if (dataSensor.SystemComponent != null)
       {
        dataSensorSystemComponent = dataSensor.SystemComponent;
       if (dataSensorSystemComponent.Subsystem != null)
       {
        location = dataSensorSystemComponent.Subsystem.MainSystem.Location;
       }
        else
       {
       location = dataSensorSystemComponent.MainSystem.Location;
       }
       }
       else if (dataSensor.Subsystem != null)
       {
       dataSensorSubsystem = dataSensor.Subsystem;
       location = dataSensorSubsystem.MainSystem.Location;
       }
       else
       {
       dataSensorMainSystem = dataSensor.MainSystem;
       location = dataSensorMainSystem.Location;
       }
```

I have code that comes next but I want it to execute only if the location pulled matches a preset number. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't really understand, do you just mean `if(location == "000102") { ... }`?

Comment: Is it that simple? Pretty much. I was going to type that but I didn't think it would work. Let me try it.